# resizing imageview with piccasso makes my app not adaptive to other device sizes

Tags: android, imageview, image-resizing

I have a layout file that represents a row item in recyclerView. That row item contains an image that is loaded though Piccaso library when going to onBindViewHolder method and is resizing the image width and height to a certain value.The issue is that is that when I am writing the value as, let's say -

```
.resize(250, 250)
```

it means that regardless of any device size it will always be 250 pixels - for a Pixel 1 that would be great, but for a Pixel 3 XL that would be tiny.

how could I make the resizing function of piccaso dynamic so I can adjust it according to the current screen size?

here is my row item XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#b0b3b7"
    android:elevation="@dimen/hero_row_elevation"
    android:tag="0"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/hero_row_corner_radius">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#b0b3b7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/heroImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/heroTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/adapterProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/heroTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroTitle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="@string/hero_row_hero_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hero_row_title_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroAbilities"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/heartImageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroAbilities"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
            android:text="@string/hero_row_abilities_text"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hero_row_abilities_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heroTitle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/heartImageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/hero_row_heart_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/hero_row_heart_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_heart"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and here is my onBindViewHolder(); method -

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HeroesViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Hero currentHero = heroList.get(position);
        String str = String.join(",", currentHero.abilities);

        holder.heroTitle.setText(currentHero.title);
        holder.heroAbilities.setText(str);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(currentHero.image)
                .resize(250, 250)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .into(holder.heroesImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                    }
                });
        if (!currentHero.isFavorite()){
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(R.drawable.empty_heart)
                    .into(holder.heartImageview);
        } else {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(R.drawable.full_heart)
                    .into(holder.heartImageview);
        }

        setFadeAnimation(holder.itemView);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use `resize()` function in Picasso, they've clearly stated the below line in their documentation [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit):

> resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect
>   aspect ratio

There is a reason why the term `"dp"` or `Density Independent Pixels` exists in Android. If you want the Image to be uniform in all the device, set the appropriate `layout_width` and `layout_height` in your layout file in `"dp"`, and it'll be uniform on all the devices regardless of their size/screen density.